# PowerMock - static methods called from delayed RxJava stream

Tags: android, rx-java2, powermock

I'm attempting to mock `BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultInstance()`, which works great per usual implementations, but is failing when the mock is accessed via a time-delayed RxJava stream.

It's as if my call to...

`when(BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()).thenReturn(null)`

...is never made and we receive a typical exception:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getDefaultAdapter in android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter not mocked`

The context is in a stream similar to:

```
Observable
  .delay(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
  .doFinally(() -> BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultInstance().getBluetoothLeScanner().stopScan())
  .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 1):

If your mocked static method is called after a delay on an RxJava stream, you must set a `TestScheduler` handler via `RxJavaPlugins` for the static mock to take effect:

```
private final TestScheduler testScheduler = new TestScheduler();

...

RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler(schedulerCallable -> testScheduler);
```